# Question on the integrability

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Suppose that neither $h$ nor $k$ is Riemann Integrable, then their product $hk$ is not Riemann Integrable. This is true, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Consider the function $f(x)$ defined on $[0,1]$ that is $1$ on the rationals and $-1$ on the irrationals. It is a standard result that $f(x)$ is not Riemann integrable, but $f^2$ surely is.

Answer (score 0):

It is not right.  Suppose $f$ is not Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$, and let $h$ extend $f$ to $[0,3]$ by making it $0$ on $(1,3]$.  Similarly, suppose $g$ is not Riemann integrable on $[2,3]$, and let $k$ extend $g$ by making it $0$ on $[0,2)$.  Then $h$ and $k$ are not Riemann integrable but $hk\equiv 0$.

(Or, as a slight modification of Potato's example, if $h$ is $1$ at rational points and $0$ at irrational points, and $k=1-h$, then $h$ and $k$ are not Riemann integrable but $hk\equiv 0$.)